# comparing two lists and finding most preferred pairs

Tags: python, list

I have two lists in like this:

```
people: ["rob", "candice", "candice", "rob", "arnold", "ben", "ben", "ben", "arnold"]
fruit: ["orange", "orange", "mango", "mango", "orange", "orange", "banana", "mango", "banana"]
```

The two lists are of people and the respective fruits they prefer. They are lists of equal length.

I am asked to find (using only lists and no dictionaries) from the fruit list, the pair of fruits that most people prefer?

Expected result here will be `("mango","orange")`. I would really appreciate help on the logic for this question. I want to code this myself.

Should I use nested `for` loops? or `zip` to run through both lists in parallel? This is some code I am working on. Trying to make a list of all the fruits, not sure if I am heading the right direction:

```
def findpair(fruit, people):
    eachfruit=[]
    seen=set()
       for i in fruit
           for j in people
               if i not in seen             
               seen.add(i)
```

Comment: He has mentioned that he wants the 'pair' of fruits most preferred, so yes, the top two basically.

Comment: yes.. I need to find the top fruit "pair"

Comment: It seems, more or less, that you are just iterating through the people list for no reason, you don't actually look at them at all.  I assume you actually want to separate each person by the fruits they prefer, and then count up the fruits for each person, but even so, it still seems there to be little reason to even care about the people in this case. Just count up the total of each fruit and take the top two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to know what fruit is preferred most, all you have to do is *count the fruits*; there is no need to pair up fruits with the people here.

The teach-yourself-to-code approach is to keep counters per fruit in a dictionary, then sorting the dictionary by value to get the most popular fruit, then the next most popular, etc.:

```
counts = {}

for fruit in fruits:
    counts[fruit] = counts.get(fruit, 0) + 1

top_fruits = sorted(counts, key=lambda fruit: counts[fruit], reversed=True)
print top_fruits[:2]
```

The Pythonic method is to use the [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) object and have it do the counting for you:

```
top_two = [fruit for fruit, count in Counter(fruits).most_common(2)]
```

which produces:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> fruits = ["orange", "orange", "mango", "mango", "orange", "orange", "banana", "mango", "banana"]
>>> [fruit for fruit, count in Counter(fruits).most_common(2)]
['orange', 'mango']
```

If you needed to count *pairs of fruit*, you'll need to do more work; [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) can help collect the per-person preferences, using [`frozenset` and `set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) to only look at unique pairs, and [`itertools.combinations()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to generate pairs of fruit per person:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
from itertools import combinations

likes = defaultdict(set)
for person, fruit in zip(persons, fruits):
    likes[person].add(fruit)

counts = Counter()
for person in likes:
    for combo in combinations(likes[person], 2):
        counts[frozenset(combo)] += 1

result = counts.most_common(1)[0][0]
```

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict, Counter
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> persons = ["rob", "candice", "candice", "rob", "arnold", "ben", "ben", "ben", "arnold"]
>>> fruits = ["orange", "orange", "mango", "mango", "orange", "orange", "banana", "mango", "banana"]
>>> likes = defaultdict(set)
>>> for person, fruit in zip(persons, fruits):
...     likes[person].add(fruit)
... 
>>> likes
defaultdict(<type 'set'>, {'ben': set(['orange', 'mango', 'banana']), 'rob': set(['orange', 'mango']), 'candice': set(['orange', 'mango']), 'arnold': set(['orange', 'banana'])})
>>> counts = Counter()
>>> for person in likes:
...     for combo in combinations(likes[person], 2):
...         counts[frozenset(combo)] += 1
... 
>>> counts.most_common(1)[0][0]
frozenset(['orange', 'mango'])
```

Comment: We all had the same there answers. I wonder why the other got downvoted :/

Comment: @JamesMills: Yeah, not sure why thefourtheye got the sharp end of the stick here. Your answer did not limit the result to just the top 2, btw.

Comment: I was getting there :)

Comment: ah! Thank you! :) but like i mentioned in the query, I am asked to do this without using dictionaries and only using lists and basic types.. anyway that this can be done?

Comment: @sameer_88: then find the *unique* fruits (build a list of those), then count each unique fruit with `list.count()`, keeping track of the top two counts and the fruits.  A lot more work!

Comment: Yes, you can do this without dictionaries, it is just more difficult, which I assume is probably the point of this assignment.

Comment: @sameer_88: so `unique_fruits = []`, `for fruit in fruits:`, `if fruit not in unique_fruits: unique_fruits.append(fruit)`, `for fruit in unique_fruit: fruit_count = fruits.count(fruit)`, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much. I created another list appending the count for each fruit and pulled out the top two

Comment: @MartijnPieters I looked over the code again, Martijn. Although this outputs the best two websites, it doesn't necessarily output the most liked 'pair'.. i.e i have to find out the number of people who like BOTH fruits.. essentially need to find all possible pairs and count the number of people who like each pair..

Comment: @sameer_88: that's all a bit more complicated, and I'm not going to do that using *just lists*. You need to identify all the different pairings and count those; `ben` likes three fruits, for example, so that's 3 unique pairs right there. I'd use a `defaultdict` with a set to collect all the likes, then use `itertools.combinations()` to produce the pairings, then count *those* with a `Counter`, etc.

Comment: @sameer_88: I hacked up the Pythonic way to do that count for you.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the expected result should be `('orange', 'mango')`. Here's the code that does what you want:

```
people = ["rob", "candice", "candice", "rob", "arnold", "ben", "ben", "ben", "arnold"]
fruit = ["orange", "orange", "mango", "mango", "orange", "orange", "banana", "mango", "banana"]
class People(object):
    def __init__(self, people, fruits):
        self.people = people
        self.fruits = fruits
        self.fruits_list = []
        for i in range(len(fruits)):
            if not hasattr(self, fruits[i]):
                setattr(self, fruits[i], 0)
            if fruits[i] not in self.fruits_list:
                self.fruits_list.append(fruits[i])
    def getFruits(self):
        for i in range(len(self.fruits)):
            setattr(self, self.fruits[i], getattr(self, self.fruits[i])+1)
        fruits_number = []
        for i in range(len(self.fruits_list)):
            fruits_number.append(getattr(self, self.fruits_list[i]))
        max_list = sorted(fruits_number, reverse=True)[0:2]
        f = ()
        for i in max_list:
            f += (self.fruits_list[fruits_number.index(i)],)
        return f
obj = People(people, fruit)
obj.getFruits()
```

This class takes two lists, `people` and `fruit` as the parameters, it loops through the `fruits` list and checks if the class instance has an attribute for each fruit, if not it sets the attributes, it also appends each fruit to the list `fruits_list`, making sure that there are no repetitions. There's a method, `getFruits()` which loops through the `fruits` list and adds 1 to the fruit attribute each time it encounters the fruit, it then loops through the `fruit_list` and appends the number of fruits in a list called `fruits_number` and gets the biggest 2 numbers in the list (stored in the `max_list` variable), then it loops through `max_list` and adds the value of the fruit in `fruits_list` with the same index as the number in `max_list stored` at `i` in `fruit_number`, finally the tuple `f` is returned.

Comment: Thank you!! I, however, must'nt use classes for this.. have to stick to just lists..

Answer (score 0):

```
class Counter(dict):
    '''Dict subclass for counting hashable items.  Sometimes called a bag
    or multiset.  Elements are stored as dictionary keys and their counts
    are stored as dictionary values.
```

So using Counter is using dict.

Only using list, you can do it this way:

```
1 sort list
2 go through list, if the fruit same as prev one, counter + 1, otherwise save the counter and fruit in result list
3 sort result list by counter and output result
```

=============================================================

```
def play():
     fruit = ["orange", "orange", "mango", "mango", "orange", "orange", "banana", "mango", "banana"]
     fruit.sort()
     result = []
     last = None

     for f in fruit:
         if last != f:
             result.append([0, f])
         else:
             result[-1][0] += 1

         last = f

      result.sort(reverse=True)

      print result[:2]
```

Comment: Thank you! Although this code outputs the first two most liked fruits, there is no guarantee that BOTH fruits are liked together by the highest set of people.. 
For. eg. if orange is liked by one set of 20 people and mango is liked by a completely different set of 20 people, the output cannot be (orange, mango) as BOTH fruits are not liked..

Essentially, I think what I need to do here is: I need to find all possible fruit pair combinations ([orange, mango], [orange,banana], etc...) and count the people who like both. Then I need to find the pair that highest number of people like.